# compare values in R when within a string of letters

Tags: r, if-statement, compare

I need to check if the values of two columns fulfil certain conditions, but the value in one column is within a string of letters.

If the value of *CURRENT_ID* is equal to the value of *CURRENT_TEXT_1* or *CURRENT_TEXT_2* plus 2, when *CURRENT_TEXT_1* or *CURRENT_TEXT_2* are equal to DISPLAY_BOUNDARY, then I need in the *OUTPUT* column a value of 1, otherwise a value of zero.

Here are some example lines of my datafile (*df*) and the output I would like to obtain:

```
 PARTICIPANT     ITEM   CONDITION      CURRENT_TEXT_1               CURRENT_TEXT_2                 CURRENT_ID            OUTPUT
 ppt01          1         1            DISPLAY_BOUNDARY 1 the       iaRegion 4 rd 0 x width 333    7                     0
 ppt01          3         1            iaRegion 2 rd 0 x width 1    DISPLAY_BOUNDARY 9 a           11                    1
 ppt01          4         2            DISPLAY_BOUNDARY 2 aware     iaRegion 6 rd 0 x width 768    3                     0
 ppt01          6         3            DISPLAY_BOUNDARY 3 door      iaRegion 8 rd 0 x width 534    4                     0
 ppt01          9         4            DISPLAY_BOUNDARY 6 in        iaRegion 9 rd 0 x width 924    5                     0
 ppt01          48        5            DISPLAY_BOUNDARY 6 the       iaRegion 10 rd 0 x width 712   8                     1
 ppt02          3         4            iaRegion 14 rd 0 x width 756 DISPLAY_BOUNDARY 15 put        17                    1
 ppt02          7         5            iaRegion 1 rd 0 x width 334  DISPLAY_BOUNDARY 1 where       3                     1
 ppt02          8         6            DISPLAY_BOUNDARY 3 At        iaRegion 2 rd 0 x width 215    5                     1
 ppt02          35        2            iaRegion 3 rd 0 x width 524  DISPLAY_BOUNDARY 1 outside     2                     0
 ppt03          10        1            iaRegion 11 rd 0 x width 190 DISPLAY_BOUNDARY 2 school      4                     1
 ppt03          56        1            DISPLAY_BOUNDARY 8 blue      iaRegion 11 red 0 x width 383  9                     0
```

My attempt is:

```
df$OUTPUT <- ifelse(df$CURRENT_ID==((grepl("DISPLAY_BOUNDARY",df$CURRENT_TEXT_1)|grepl("DISPLAY_BOUNDARY",df$CURRENT_TEXT_2))+2, 1, 0)
```

But I don't know how to extract the value associated with DISPLAY_BOUNDARY. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you visualize a comparison between a  numeric value `CURRENT_ID` and a character one (`CURRENT_TEXT_1`)? I mean, which lines in the current example comply with `CURRENT_TEXT_1==CURRENT_ID` ?

Comment: Try using `gsub` instead of `grepl` : `df$OUTPUT=ifelse((df$CURRENT_ID==as.numeric(gsub("DISPLAY_BOUNDARY (\\d+).*","\\1",df$CURRENT_TEXT_1))-2) | (df$CURRENT_ID==as.numeric(gsub("DISPLAY_BOUNDARY (\\d+).*","\\1",df$CURRENT_TEXT_2))-2),1,0)`

Comment: the value I want to compare in CURRENT_TEXT_1 or CURRENT_TEXT_2 is the one after DISPLAY_BOUNDARY.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the result of a `dput` of your dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps...

```
#extract any relevant numeric values from ct1 and ct2
ct1 <- as.numeric(gsub("DISPLAY_BOUNDARY ([0-9]+).*","\\1",df$CURRENT_TEXT_1))  
ct2 <- as.numeric(gsub("DISPLAY_BOUNDARY ([0-9]+).*","\\1",df$CURRENT_TEXT_2))

#use mapply to check each row and return logical value as numeric
df$OUTPUT <- as.numeric(mapply(function(id,x1,x2) id %in% c(x1+2,x2+2),
                               as.numeric(df$CURRENT_ID),ct1,ct2))
```

Comment: I am not very familiar with functions. Could you please explain why we added +2 to x2 but not x1? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry - I misread the question as meaning ct1 or ct2+2. If it is ct1+2 as well, then it should be `x1+2`  in the function too. I will amend the answer.