# compare values in R with a function

Tags: r, if-statement, compare

This is a follow up from a previous post: [compare values in R when within a string of letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44289648/compare-values-in-r-when-within-a-string-of-letters)

I need to check if the value of *CURRENT_ID* is equal or equal plus 1 to the value of *CURRENT_TEXT_1* or *CURRENT_TEXT_2*, when *CURRENT_TEXT_1* or *CURRENT_TEXT_2* are equal to DISPLAY_BOUNDARY. If it is, then I need in the *OUTPUT* column a value of 1, otherwise a value of zero.

Here are some example lines of my datafile (*df*) and the output I would like to obtain:

```
 PARTICIPANT     ITEM   CONDITION      CURRENT_TEXT_1               CURRENT_TEXT_2                 CURRENT_ID            OUTPUT
 ppt01          1         1            DISPLAY_BOUNDARY 1 the       iaRegion 4 rd 0 x width 333    7                     0
 ppt01          3         1            iaRegion 2 rd 0 x width 1    DISPLAY_BOUNDARY 9 a           11                    0
 ppt01          4         2            DISPLAY_BOUNDARY 2 aware     iaRegion 6 rd 0 x width 768    3                     1
 ppt01          6         3            DISPLAY_BOUNDARY 3 door      iaRegion 8 rd 0 x width 534    4                     1
 ppt01          9         4            DISPLAY_BOUNDARY 6 in        iaRegion 9 rd 0 x width 924    5                     1
 ppt01          48        5            DISPLAY_BOUNDARY 6 the       iaRegion 10 rd 0 x width 712   8                     0
 ppt02          3         4            iaRegion 14 rd 0 x width 756 DISPLAY_BOUNDARY 15 put        17                    0
 ppt02          7         5            iaRegion 1 rd 0 x width 334  DISPLAY_BOUNDARY 1 where       3                     0
 ppt02          8         6            DISPLAY_BOUNDARY 3 At        iaRegion 2 rd 0 x width 215    5                     0
 ppt02          35        2            iaRegion 3 rd 0 x width 524  DISPLAY_BOUNDARY 1 outside     2                     1
 ppt03          10        1            iaRegion 11 rd 0 x width 190 DISPLAY_BOUNDARY 2 school      4                     0
 ppt03          56        1            DISPLAY_BOUNDARY 8 blue      iaRegion 11 red 0 x width 383  9                     1
```

Is it correct to do:

```
ct3 <- as.numeric(gsub("DISPLAY_BOUNDARY ([0-9]+).*","\\1",df$CURRENT_TEXT_1))  
ct4 <- as.numeric(gsub("DISPLAY_BOUNDARY ([0-9]+).*","\\1",df$CURRENT_TEXT_2))

df$OUTPUT <- as.numeric(mapply(function(id,x1,x2,x3,x4) id %in% c(x1+1,x2+1,x1,x2), as.numeric(df$CURRENT_ID),ct3,ct4,ct3,ct4))
```

I am not sure about `function(id,x1,x2,x3,x4)` if I need to put x3 and x4, and about `,ct3,ct4,ct3,ct4)` if I need to write twice ct3 and ct4.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "I need to check if the value of CURRENT_ID is equal or equal plus 1 to the value of CURRENT_TEXT_1 or CURRENT_TEXT_2, when CURRENT_TEXT_1 or CURRENT_TEXT_2 are equal to DISPLAY_BOUNDARY". For instance on row 5 of your data.frame, the number right after DISPLAY_BOUNDARY is 6 and the the CURRENT_ID is 5, yet the Output is 0.

Comment: @Taran, you're right. I modified it.

Comment: @Mako212, could you please explain why?

Comment: @dede could you dput the sample of the df you are showing so that it can be easily imported into an Rsession

Comment: @dede Let me clarify, what I was seeing is that in your example, `x1 == x3`, and `x2 == x4`. This means you can write your function as: `function(id,x1,x2) id %in% c(x1+1,x2+1,x1,x2)`, and moreover, you're not even using `x3` and `x4` in your function.